# Liquibase sets DEFAULT 0 for BIT

Tags: liquibase

I add the following column in a table:

```
alter table my_table
    add no_default bit null;
```

When I let Liquibase make a diff, it generates the following change:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD no_default BIT DEFAULT 0 NULL;
```

As you see, it sets `false` (`0`) as default value although the column does not define it.
Is this an error or is there a way to prevent this?

// Edit: I am using a MariaDB 10.2 database.

Comment: I don't know much about liquibase, but if the column type is bit then what would the binary representation of a null value be?

Comment: BIT can still be null, so what I would expect is `BIT DEFAULT NULL NULL` or just `BIT NULL`.